# IntelliJ IDEA diff in Version Control

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, version-control, diff, jetbrains-ide

How do I view the diff on IntelliJ **right next to** the list of changed files as done on Android Studio?

Android Studio diff:

[image: Android Studio diff]

IntelliJ IDEA diff:

[image: IntelliJ IDEA diff]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable **Preview Diff** in the Local Changes toolbar. It is the last icon on the toolbar, on your screenshots, it is hidden under `>>`